# How can I get more information about my iPhone's Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: ios, network, wifi

Tapping the information icon in Settings → Wi-Fi → (current connection) shows me a small amount of network information (mostly IP bits) about my Wi-Fi connection.

I just enabled WPA3 on my network, though, and I want to confirm that my iPhone is using it.

On my MacBook, if I hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and click the Wi-Fi menu, I can see a lot of other information about my Wi-Fi connection, such as

- Router address
- Security *(this is what I want!)*
- Channel and signal strength information

Is this information available in iOS and where?

Answer (score 1):

Other than router address (just tap on the information icon - the blue "I" in the circle on the right), it doesn't display any of this other information because both of those are handled automatically.

If you need that info, you'll need a separate, 3rd party app.

- [Status Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/system-status-pro-hw-monitor/id401457165) (Lite version definately doesn't have it)
- [WiFi Advisor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wifi-advisor/id944323575) (Free)

Those are just two of the options available.  Many commercial network manufacturers have much more robust utilities but, you have to have their products installed in order for them to work.

That said, channel and security (WPA/WPA2 Personal or Enterprise, Certificates, etc) weren't of any real use because unless doing in depth diagnosis because we set our WAPs to [automatic channel switching](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386973/119271) meaning the channel we saw one moment would change the next and security wasn't important unless we were analyzing a customers network, but we easily got that info from Windows networking settings when we tried to connect.