# Internet Sharing: restricted set of WiFi channels

Tags: wifi, high-sierra, airport, internet-sharing

I am using *Internet Sharing* since many versions of macOS to extend my Ethernet connection on the WiFi (or Airport) side.

Until Yosemite, within *Internet Sharing > WiFi Options…* it was possible to select a WiFi channel to use among:

```
2,4 GHz    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
5   GHz    36,40,44,48
```

Now, on the same Mac (on which I test High Sierra to check I will be able to use it) I see the following set of channels:

[image]

Unfortunately, all these channels are overcrowded by my neighbors (3 to 5 on each of these channels) and can't be used.

On the other hand, channel 8 is free of any neighbor, and work perfectly well on the same Mac (running Yosemite) and on all my other Macs and iPhones.

1. How may I select this channel?
2. Which program built this small list of channels?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't select a channel manually, let auto-select handle it for you.**

> Unfortunately, all these channels are overcrowded by my neighbors (3 to 5 on each of these channels) and can't be used.

You're absolutely correct - at this moment.  This changes continually as traffic increases/decreases.

[How can I use my Mac to determine the optimal WiFi channel to use with my wireless router?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/386863/119271)

As people light up hot spots, turn on AirPlay, AirDrop, screen casting, etc. it all "lives" in the same 2.4 and 5GHz bandwidths.  Letting your Mac or WAP automatically detect and switch channels for you will ensure you get the cleanest channel at the time.

> Which program build this small list of channels?

That was created dynamically.  Those are the channels that have the "best" signals at that moment.

Now, if bandwidth congestion and more than likely noise are causing connectivity issues, it's much better to get multiple WAPs (Wireless Access Points) with the transmit power *reduced* than to get one, crank up the power and shoehorn it into a particular channel.  Think of it like trying to setup  speakers for a party in a noisy environment.  It's better to have several speakers dialed to maybe a 4 or a 5 than to just have one speaker cranked up to 11 and then the knob subsequently broken off.

Additionally, getting a newer, modern WAP (you don't need a full blown router) will give you much better performance because you'll have the option of placing it higher up (like on a shelf or bookcase) where devices will have better line of sight to the antennae as opposed to the MacBook on a desk.

Comment: From my experiments the auto-select is a big failure in any Wi-Fi maker because this technic is ill conceived. It doesn’t take into account the fact that the wireless environment is a living one: people turn off their TV, arrive home with their iPhone, change room, go to breakfast, turn on the Bluetooth speaker, the fridge Bluetooth changed channel as it does all the time… For the fun: a wireless network size shrink with humidity (because water absorbs radio frequencies in the cm range).

Comment: @dan and you think *manually* locking into a channel is going to fix all of that?  In the past, yes.  Modern wireless from the past 5 years alone has come a long, long, way.

Comment: With a good frequency analysis tool I see that on a full day channel 1 is always overloaded to an unacceptable noise level, next is channel 6 and in third position is channel 11. Channels 3, 4, 8, 9, 13 are empty and their level of noise is around -96 dB. On a full year I never had to change my channel to improve signal / noise level with about 50 neighbors networks.

Comment: You’re surrounded by people, likely, with older routers using old tech.  Let a few people upgrade and that will change.  You’re scenario is definitely an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on why you only see specific choices, however it's **highly recommended you stick with one of the three main channel choices 1, 6, or 11**.

After doing CWNP (wireless)certifications they made it clear that there would be a lot less trouble by choosing one of the three channels mentioned above, even if the three channels are quite active.

When you choose channel 8, it's actually picking up interference and causing interference on everything from channel 6 through channel 10!

Your best bet is to use a WiFi scanner app and find out which of the three options are a little weaker and use that channel, or keep things set on Automatic. The neighbor's WiFi access points/routers will likely switch around between channels as well, so setting things manually in such a dense setup is a bit of a risk.

Allan had great other suggestions as well and I agree with all -- consider a Wireless Access Point. I used to use Internet Connection Sharing and the performance was pretty dismal compared with decent access points. (Weak signal strength, slower connectivity, way less options)

See this article for more details on picking one of the three channels and why it's bad to choose a adjacent channel, such as channel 8:
[Why Channels 1, 6, and 11?](https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html)

Comment: In my home environment and years of experiment channels 1, 6 and 11 can’t be used: they are overloaded by all my neighbors and the stupid auto-select channel algorithm all makers are aligned on.

Comment: To be honest from a pure technical point of vue the non overlapping channel scheme on the 2.4 GHz band is: 1, 5, 9, 13. The 1, 6, 11 scheme was recommended for poor quality radio-frequency electronics which were leaking beyond their channel 20 years ago (one channel = 20 MHz). Such leaking electronics aren’t any more in use today even with the worst makers.